# Inner join update query not running

Tags: mysql

Error in the mysql syntax .I have used two tables to join them using inner join

```
update wp_postmeta 
set  sku.meta_value=seo.`Meta Description`  
From sanitaryseo AS  seo 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS sku 
ON sku.meta_value = seo.`product code`
where sku.meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the table and the join in top

```
update wp_postmeta sku
inner join sanitaryseo seo ON sku.meta_value = seo.`product code`
set  sku.meta_value=seo.`Meta Description`  
where sku.meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc';
```

And remember that Update clause don't use from  .. (the table or the tables joined  are in update clause)

Comment: Update you question and show me the real code you are using ... please

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 UPDATE wp_postmeta t1
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta t2 
ON t1.meta_value = t2.`product code`    
SET t1.meta_value=t2.`Meta Description`
WHERE t1.meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc';
```

Comment: i think the error was due to absence of single quotes around Meta Description. Because it contains a sapce. Now corrected. Please check